# Can a thread jump over lock()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have a `class` that provides thread-safe access to `LinkedList<>` (adding and reading items).

```
class LinkedListManager {
    public static object locker = new object();
    public static LinkedList<AddXmlNodeArgs> tasks { get; set; }
    public static EventWaitHandle wh { get; set; }

    public void AddItemThreadSafe(AddXmlNodeArgs task) {
        lock (locker)
            tasks.AddLast(task);
        wh.Set();
    }

    public LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> GetNextItemThreadSafe(LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> prevItem) {
        LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> nextItem;
        if (prevItem == null) {
            lock (locker)
                return tasks.First;
        }
        lock (locker) // *1
            nextItem = prevItem.Next;
        if (nextItem == null) { // *2
            wh.WaitOne();
            return prevItem.Next;
        }
        lock (locker)
            return nextItem;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 threads: 1st - writes data to `tasks`; 2nd and 3rd - read data from `tasks`.

In 2nd and 3rd threads I retrieve data from `tasks` by calling `GetNextItemThreadSafe()`.

**The problem is** that sometimes `GetNextItemThreadSafe()` returns `null`, when parameter of method (`prevItem`) is not null`.

**Question:**

Can a thread somehow jump over `lock(locker)` (`// *1`) and get to `// *2` at once ??

I think it's the only way to get a return value = `null` from `GetNextItemThreadSafe()`...

I've spend a whole day to find the mistake, but it's extremely hard because it seems to be almost impossible to debug it step by step (`tasks` contains 5.000 elements and error occurs whenever it wants). Btw sometimes program works fine - without exception.

I'm new to threads so maybe I'm asking silly questions...

Comment: The answer is no. Check your function's logic again.

Comment: @shay__ I'm reviewing it over and over the whole day long and I don't understand how can `GetNextItemThreadSafe()` return `null`... If I put breakpoint to `wh.WaitOne()` - it is being hit sometimes, but I'm pretty sure that this thread have not reached the end of `LinkedList` yet. And if so, line `nextItem = prevItem.Next;` had to return something different from `null`

Comment: You are reading prevItem.Next outside of the lock while a concurrent thread could mutate the list meanwhile. That's a data race and therefore a bug.

Comment: Also, it looks like you can miss a signal. Two writers can signal the handle. That results in one lost signal. I believe this can lead to one items remaining in the list while a reader is waiting. Consider just using a BlockingCollection.

Comment: @usr I've tried to wrap `prevItem.Next` into `lock()` but it had no effect. Btw I'm not sure, but I think that `prevItem` is not connected to `tasks`, and `.Next` is just a field inside the instance...

Comment: @usr I'm not sure, but if two threads call `wh.WaitOne()` - they are just placed in some kind of queue, but they won't be missed. They will just wait two `wh.Set()` commands

Answer (score 0):

A `lock` is only active when executing the block of code declared following the lock.  Since you lock multiple times on single commands, this effectively degenerates to only locking the single command that follows the `lock`, after which another thread is free to jump in and consume the data.  Perhaps what you meant is this:

```
public LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> GetNextItemThreadSafe(LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> prevItem) {
    LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> nextItem;
    LinkedListNode<AddXmlNodeArgs> returnItem;

    lock(locker) { // Lock the entire method contents to make it atomic
      if (prevItem == null) {
        returnItem = tasks.First;
      }

      // *1
      nextItem = prevItem.Next;

      if (nextItem == null) { // *2
        // wh.WaitOne(); // Waiting in a locked block is not a good idea
        returnItem = prevItem.Next;
      }

      returnItem = nextItem;
    }

    return returnItem;
  }
}
```

Note that only assignments (as opposed to returns) occur within the locked block and there is a single return point at the bottom of the method.

Comment: Assume that `LinkedList` contains 800 elements. One thread is on the 800th element and it locks the whole method. While the other thread is on 400th element, but it can't process data because method `GetNextItemThreadSafe()` is locked. Am I right? Or it won't slow performance ?

Comment: And why can't I use `return` keyword inside a locked block ?

Comment: If you wait inside the lock, then AddItemThreadSafe will be locked as well, and wont'be able to add a node (and set the event) Deadlock.

Comment: (1) In your example, #1 only locks the assignment.  At that point, and before the return, another thread can jump in.  (2) I expect that you can return from within a lock, but it's unclear what happens if you do, and you can make your method clearer with one exit point.  (3) Do you want fast, incorrect performance or slow, correct performance? Also, why would you want to wait here? (Commenting that out as it does seem incorrect).

Comment: @PeterGluck I thought it's a right place to wait... `if (nextItem == null)` says that if the item is the last one in collection - thread should wait for at least one more item to be added.

Comment: @PeterGluck Perhaps you meant `nextItem = prevItem.Next;`, not `returnItem = prevItem.Next;` within `if (nextItem == null)`.

Comment: @jamesbong, you're right, you have to wait, but the logic is broken if both consumer threads are waiting, because only one of them will be unlocked by the Set() call

Comment: @PeterGluck where should I place `wh.WaitOne()` if the whole method is wrapped in `lock()` ?

Comment: I would really go for 2 BlockingCollection, each one being consumed by one of your worker thread. This would solve all synchronisation issues, which are very tricky to address.

Comment: @Thierry too much code to rewrite ((( but I will if I don't find the answer

Comment: @PeterGluck btw your code runs into the same exception as mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you're trying to achieve. Are both threads supposed to get the same elements of the linked list ? Or are you trying to have 2 threads process the tasks out of the list in parallel ? If it's the second case, then what you are doing cannot work. You'd better look at BlockingCollection which is thread-safe and designed for this kind of multi-threaded producers/consumers patterns.

Comment: Both threads retrieve each element of `tasks` collection, but they do different things with this data (one thread addes it to a `TreeView`, the other one writes it to XML-file)

Comment: And you never remove nodes from the linked list ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is the following:

In your Add method, add the node **and** set the EventWaitHandle **both** inside the same lock

In the Get method, inside a lock, check if the next element is empty **and** inside the same lock, Reset the EventWaitHandle. Outside of the lock, wait on the EventWaitHandle.